# sum of the log over the log of the count (Average of probablities)

Tags: probability, logarithms, average

I wondering if anyone has seen this "averaging" technique before, and what its advantages might be?  The values being averages are probabilities and as such have a value of 1 or less.

$\frac{1}{log(n)} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(a_i)$
where $n > 1$

This is being used in a language model claiming to be using Kneser-Ney Smoothing.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? For instance, where did you see that used?

Comment: If you have $0 \lt a_i \lt 1$ and $n \gt 1$ then you calculation gives a negative result.  If $n=1$ it does not give a result at all.  Meanwhile $\exp\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(a_i)\right)$ would be a geometric average.